# Maximize a function involving binary entropy

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, maxima-minima, information-theory, entropy

I have the following function:
$$ f(\gamma)=\log _{2}\left(1+2^ {\frac{h\left(p_{0}\right)-h\left(p_{1}\right)}{p_{0}-p_{1}}}{}\right)+\frac{(1-p_{1}) h\left(p_{0}\right)-(1-p_{0}) h\left(p_{1}\right)}{p_{1}-p_{0}}$$
where $h(p) = -p\log_2 p - (1 - p)\log_2(1 - p)$ is the [binary entropy function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_entropy_function), and
$$p_0=1-e^\frac{-\gamma^2}{a^2}, \quad p_1=1-e^\frac{-\gamma^2}{a^2+b^2}.$$

**Question**: For given values of $a$ and $b$, what value of $\gamma$ maximizes $f(\gamma)$?
I am trying to come up with an ***analytical expression for this optimal value of $\gamma$.***

Can someone help me to **analytically** find the optimal $\gamma$.? I am ok with good approximations as well.

Comment: I do not understand why you care about the definition of $(p_0,p_1)$

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? :(

Comment: Be sure I never downvoted your questions. In a comment, I was just wondering something that you never clarified

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  $p_0$ and $p_1$ are constrained to be of that form by the model I am considering. The only tunable parameter is $\gamma$ . So that is why I want to find $\gamma$ which maximizes the function.

Comment: @wanderer I edited your post. Check if it is ok.

Comment: @RiverLi yes, it's ok

Comment: Is this function convex? Have you tried plotting it? It looks like some sort of rate plus some sort of normalized false alarm and those might have multiple extremums.

Comment: With the substitution $-\frac{\gamma^2}{a^2} = \ln x$ for $x\in (0, 1)$, the problem boils down to finding $x\in (0, 1)$ to maximize
$$f(x) = \log_2\left(1 + 2^{- \dfrac{h(x^c) - h(x)}{x^c - x}}\right) + x\cdot \frac{h(x^c) - h(x)}{x^c - x} - h(x)$$
where $c = \frac{a^2}{a^2 + b^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from @River Li's last comment, solving $f'(x)=0$ for a given value of $c$ is not bad from a numerical point of view since $f'(x)$ is a smooth function (more or less looking like an hyperbola).

Some results obtained using Newton method
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
c & x \\
 0.00 &  0.000000 \\
 0.01 &  0.005313 \\
 0.02 &  0.009586 \\
 0.03 &  0.013397 \\
 0.04 &  0.016907 \\
 0.05 &  0.020195 \\
 0.10 &  0.034588 \\
 0.15 &  0.047012 \\
 0.20 &  0.058343 \\
 0.25 &  0.068978 \\
 0.30 &  0.079138 \\
 0.35 &  0.088957 \\
 0.40 &  0.098522 \\
 0.45 &  0.107890 \\
 0.50 &  0.117101 \\
 0.55 &  0.126179 \\
 0.60 &  0.135141 \\
 0.65 &  0.143996 \\
 0.70 &  0.152751 \\
 0.75 &  0.161408 \\
 0.80 &  0.169966 \\
 0.85 &  0.178426 \\
 0.90 &  0.186784 \\
 0.95 &  0.195039 \\
 0.96 &  0.196677 \\
 0.97 &  0.198311 \\
 0.98 &  0.199941 \\
 0.99 &  0.201567
\end{array}
\right)$$
This looks like a power law and an empirical curve fit
$$x=\alpha \,c^{\beta}$$ gives $(R^2=0.999981)$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 \alpha  & 0.202615 & 0.000210 & \{0.202183,0.203046\} \\
 \beta   & 0.781326 & 0.002224 & \{0.776755,0.785897\} \\
\end{array}$$ and the maximum absolute error is $\sim 0.0011$ and an average error of $0.0005$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It is quite helpful. Could you clarify what is $R^2$?

Comment: @wanderer. Correlation coefficient $R^2=1$ would mean *perfection*

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and I have accepted the answer. Could you also comment on which software you used for curve-fitting? I am working on another similar problem (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4329422/maximize-the-variance-of-a-function-of-random-variable).  I am thinking of using a curve-fitting approach.

Comment: @wanderer. Why don't you register at Wolfram Cloud ? It is free and you have access to all Mathematica. Otherwise, jus for curve fitting, on the Internet, there are many on-line tools. Thanks & cheers. :-)