# Maximize the variance of a function of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, optimization, numerical-methods, random-variables

I have a function $f(X)=\exp\left(\frac{-\gamma^2}{a^2X+b^2}\right)$ where $X \sim \mathrm{Binomial}(n,p)$.  I am interested in finding the value of $\gamma^2$ which **maximizes the variance of $f(X)$**  for given values of $a$ and $b$.

**Definition of variance**:
$$
\operatorname{var}(f(X))=\mathrm{E}\left(f^2(X)\right)-\left(\mathrm{E}\bigl(f(X) \bigl) \right)^{2}
$$
From Expectation of Function of Discrete Random Variable:

$$E\left(f^2(X)\right)=\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \exp\left(\frac{-2\gamma^2}{a^2k+b^2}\right) {n \choose k} p^{k} (1-p)^{n-k}$$
$$E\left(f(X)\right)=\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \exp\left(\frac{-\gamma^2}{a^2k+b^2}\right)  {n \choose k} p^{k} (1-p)^{n-k}$$

To me, *it seems NOT straightforward how to solve $\mathrm{d}[\operatorname{var}(f(X))]/\mathrm{d}\gamma=0$ to find an expression for optimal $\gamma^2$.*

Hence, I am thinking of **at least finding a numerically accurate solution through curve-fitting.**

**My aim is to come up with a "working formula" for optimal $\gamma$ in terms of the other parameters.**

Also, I have MATLAB and I am wondering how formulate this problem and find an expression using MATLAB as well.

**Some context on $f(X)$**: *$f(X)$ comes from the complementary CDF of an exponential distribution. There are $X$ signal components with power $a^2$ and a non-signal component with power $b^2$. Also, $\gamma^2$ is a threshold at which we evaluate the function.*

Comment: Just trying a toy example, it seems the variance is a concave function of $\gamma$. Can that be proven? Anyway I'd try an iterative search. But that won't get you a formula.

Comment: Can you explain why you gave up on finding the gradient?  Those sums at the end seem straightforward to differentiate to me.

Comment: @CharlesF , I am not sure how to proceed after I take the derivative. For me, finding the root of the derivative  looked complex because of the summations involved. I would appreciate if you could suggest how to solve the equation: Derivative=0 to get an expression for optimal $\gamma^2$.

Comment: I’m agree finding the roots of the gradient isn’t easy, but a numerical approach to that should be straightforward to do in a computer, as opposed to a numerical approach directly on the function var(F). Analytically finding the roots of the gradient would only be possible if you got really lucky with some way so simplify the coefficients in the series.

Comment: This expectation is a differentiable function of $\gamma,$ so maybe that can help.

Comment: I could find the maximum at $x=\sqrt{2\log 2}$ for $n=1, a=b=1$. One basically has to solve a polynomial equation in $e^{-\gamma^2}$. For $n>1$ it becomes less trivial and needs some ideas. I also made [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5iz6ddiqyk), to get a feeling of how things look.

Comment: That's why I'm thinking of a curve fitting approach which would give more insight. Also in my case, $p$ is actually close to 0. $p \approx 1-2^{-1/n}$.

Comment: For a finite, discrete random variable, you can write 

$$Var(X) = \frac{1}{2}p^TQp$$
where $p$ is the probability distribution: $P(X = x_i) = p_i$ and $Q_{ij} = (x_i-x_j)^2.$ Normally, the minimum value of this when $p$ varies is the smallest eigenvalue of $Q.$ But in your case $Q = Q(\gamma)$ is the variable, so it's a bit iffy.

Answer (score 1):

This answer tries to come up with a working formula, although an approximate one.

I use the following approximate value to the variance of a function of a random variable:
$$\operatorname{Var}\left[f(X)\right] \approx \left(f'(\operatorname{E}\left[X\right])\right)^2\operatorname{Var}\left[X\right] $$

In this case, $\operatorname{E}\left[X\right]=np$  and $$\frac{d}{d X}f|_{X=np}=\exp \left(\frac{-\gamma^2}{a^2np+b^2}\right)\frac{a^2\gamma^2}{(a^2np+b^2)^2}$$

I set aside the constant $\operatorname{Var}\left[X\right]$.

Maximizing the square of a function is equivalent to maximizing the function itself.

Letting $$ z:= \frac{\gamma^2}{a^2 n p+b^2}$$ $$ C:= \frac{a^2}{a^2np+b^2}$$ the next step is to maximize the function $z \mapsto C z \exp(-z)$ over the positive reals.

The standard procedure gives $z=1$ which amounts to $$\gamma^2= a^2 np+b^2$$.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The problem with this is that the approximation of $Var[f(X)]$ is not a good one. This is explained at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/452523/the-correct-way-to-approximate-textvarfx-via-taylor-expansion?rq=1 

I also checked here (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5iz6ddiqyk) to verify that the derived $\gamma^2$ is indeed not a good approximation.

The most general form of variance approximation is given here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/452544/what-is-the-general-second-order-taylor-approximation-to-mathbbvfx